# Spinning a rope when hanging, what is the curve?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, variational-principle

Holding a rope from one end and spinning it. As shown in the picture, what will be the curve of it? 
[image]

Comment: Take a chain (it is better than a rope) and spin it. You will see what happens and answer you own question.

Comment: @Energizer777 I suspect that noamgolani is asking for an equation for the curve of the rope/chain.

Comment: The answer probably depends on rotational speeds, flexibility, rope length, and a few other factors that I'm not immediately thinking of.

Comment: My guess would be an equation like $z=c_1-c_2{\theta}^2$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants. And a constant radius (cylindrical system)

Comment: The centripetal force is a 'stand-in' for gravity, and I suspect you are seeing a catenary of some sort, but since the lower end is not constrained ... ? Good question & like the catenary, the calculus of variations and minimizing energy may be the route to solving this question.

Comment: @docscience - I thought that the curve might be simply related to a catenary at first, too, but in addition to being constrained at both ends a centenary is the result of a spatially uniform (gravitational) force field. In contrast, the centripetal force here is not spatially uniform: It increases with distance away from the axis of rotation, so different parts of the rope feel different effective "gravitational" pulls outward.

Comment: @docscience The centrifugal force can indeed be thought of as a gravitational field in the co-rotating frame, but in this case it's an inhomogeneous field since the centrifugal force is proportional to the distance from the axis, so it cannot be a catenary.

Comment: @KyleKanos There likely is only one meaningful parameter. A reasonable model is a perfectly flexible, thin rope. There is only one external dimensional parameter ($g$) and it is matched dimensionally by the combination $L\omega^2$ of the length $L$ and angular velocity $\omega$ of the spinning, so the curve does have one 'shape' parameter $L\omega^2/g$, but that's it. This is a perfectly well-defined question with a perfectly well-defined answer - I don't see the grounds for a 'too broad' close vote. (Not implying that it's yours!)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: Sure, if you want to consider only the steady-state case, the shape would be a circle/spiral/arc-length. But if you're actually going to describe the shape, then you've got a [10-page paper on it](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.4941) or [a book chapter](https://repositories.lib.utexas.edu/handle/2152/3741). I see grounds for 'too broad' for that reason (and one is indeed mine).

Comment: @KyleKanos The book chapter is a red herring - it's quite clear the question does not ask for an extensive treatment of interactions with the surrounding fluid. An appropriate summary of Hanna's paper would make an excellent answer, which I invite you to write. Alternatively, a helpful comment pointing the OP to that paper would have been much more friendly to a newcomer. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: @Emilio: I try not answering questions that I believe are off-topic.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22268/2451